# grab image using curl_exec not working on certain domain

Tags: php, image, curl

`enter code here`Previously, the below function to save image from a certain "$url" to "$saveto" was working properly. Somehow, when i try to grab this domain picture, i.e. http://pic.pimg.tw/ellenitn/4a439fc4b1c2e.jpg
It failed to work anymore (it was working 2 days ago and now it stopped working, the images saved is all 0kb)

```
function grab_image($url,$saveto)
{
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$raw=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if(file_exists($saveto)){
    unlink($saveto);
}

$fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
$var = fwrite($fp, $raw); 
fclose($fp);

return $var;
}
```

Can I know how to go around debugging this? I have tried file_get_contents(), but it failed to work as well, code error -> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known.

Edited:

When I use:

```
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

I got this information:

```
Array ( 
[url] => http://pic.pimg.tw/ellenitn/4a439fc4b1c2e.jpg 
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0 
[header_size] => 0 
[request_size] => 0 
[filetime] => 0 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0 
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 0 
[namelookup_time] => 0  
[connect_time] => 0  
[pretransfer_time] => 0  
[size_upload] => 0  
[size_download] => 0  
[speed_download] => 0  
[speed_upload] => 0  
[download_content_length] => -1  
[upload_content_length] => -1  
[starttransfer_time] => 0  
[redirect_time] => 0  
[certinfo] => Array ( )  
[primary_ip] =>  
[redirect_url] =>  
)
```

Comment: but why  http://pic.pimg.tw/ellenitn/4a439fc4b1c2e.jpg is still accessible?

Comment: _Weird_, it is not accessible for me. I also verified it [here](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/)

Comment: I have printed curl_getinfo, anything that can shed some light on what happen? i notice the return http_code is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The given URL returns an "unknown host" error.

As from your code, you are not doing any error handling. Suppose the following:

- the server name is wrong (as the above url)
- the server doesn't respond
- the server gives an error (http 50x)
- the link is not an image
- the link is gone (http 40x)

you need to catch all of the above in order to be sure to actually got at least what you want before starting to save something to a file.

As from your try:

> I have tried file_get_contents(), but it failed to work as well, code
>   error -> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service
>   not known.

you are getting the proper error message already. `file_get_contents()`will give you all needed control to handle such errors.

Answer (score 0):

**1: Downloading a file and saving it with file_put_contents()**

```
   <?php
        $url  = 'http://pic.pimg.tw/ellenitn/4a439fc4b1c2e.jpg;
        $savepath = '/local/path/to/4a439fc4b1c2e.jpg'; //make sure you have write permissions on "/local/path/to/"

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        file_put_contents($savepath, $data);
    ?>
```

**2: Use cURL to download straight to a file stream**

```
<?php
    $url  = 'http://pic.pimg.tw/ellenitn/4a439fc4b1c2e.jpg';
    $savepath = '/local/path/to/4a439fc4b1c2e.jpg';

    $fp = fopen($savepath, 'w');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```